# javascript to refer to img url: best practices?

Tags: javascript

I have written a tiny bit of javascript which uses two images.

inside the code it does something like

```
str+='<img src="left.jpg"></img>';
...
str+='<img src="right.jpg"></img>';
...
```

The script works very well. 
The problem is that depending which HTML page uses my script I might get the images broken.

I could solve the problem by defining a directory /img for all the images but I would rather not. 
I would rather pack the images required by each script in their folders.

Can somebody suggest how to do this ?  or what are the best practices for doing this

thanks

Comment: You might get a broken image because the second `<img>` has no `src`.

Comment: Well, the links to the images depend on the HTML file it will be shown in, not the script used to make it appear. There's no way around that.

Comment: in your image src, add ../ this is a short cut that tells the browser to look for the image at the root of the application.

Answer (score 0):

But all HTML pages that use your script are, I suppose, in different folders. They try to find images in their folder, and images appear on the page which is in the same folder as images. So you can:

- Place all HTML pages in one folder (and images in the same folder)
- Create a separate folder for images and access that folder in the pages
- *[not recommended]* Make a copy of all the images for each HTML page.